# Why is a pointer value is changed once being returned?

Tags: c, memory

Disclaimer: This is for a homework assignment but the question being asked is unrelated to the actual assignment.

I have to implement a simple memory manager for one of my classes, in the function my_malloc just before the return from the function the value that is being return is one this (say: 0x7fb0049ed410) and in the calling function is it another (say: 0x49ed410).

my_malloc(unsigned int);

```
typedef void* Addr;
Addr raddr = (Addr) (memoryHeader + sizeof(header)))
printf("Giving Memory: %p : %p\n", addr, raddr);
return raddr
```

calling function();

```
void* mem = my_malloc(10*sizeof(char));
printf("Calling Function: %p\n", mem);
```

I'm sorry if this isn't helpful but I thought this might be enough to get the problem across without giving all 600 and something line of code.

Warning begin given:

```
incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'void *' from 'int'
```

Comment: What is `memoryHeader`? Is it on the stack or the heap? I don't think you need 600 lines of code, but perhaps 20 or 30 lines of code that can **reproduce** the problem is necessary to describe the problem.

Comment: It would help if the problem was reproducible.  i.e. A Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example would help; http://sscce.org/

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Im sorry, but I do not have enough time to create an example. However, I did learn that the two values that are being printed are the same when casted to integers.

Answer (score 1):

The code calling the `my_malloc()` function probably isn't being given a proper declaration/prototype for the function, so it's treating the returned pointer as an `int`.

Place the following before the call to `my_malloc()` (ideally this should be in a header that is included by any code that calls the function as well as the code that defines so the function to ensure it's correct).

```
void* my_malloc(size_t size);
```

Comment: Then I think you'll need to find the time to post an example instead of incomplete snippets.